# Find heading text and select next shape or inline shape in word vba

Tags: vba, ms-word

In my below code I'm trying to find the next occurrence of shape or inline shape after the text selected.
But nothing works... Please, I need help here:

```vb
With Selection.Find
.Text = Text
.Replacement.Text = ""
.Forward = True
.Wrap = 1
.Format = False
.MatchCase = match_case
.MatchWholeWord = match_whole_word
.MatchWildcards = False
.MatchSoundsLike = False
.MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
    Do While f.Execute = True
            s.Next(Unit:=wdParagraph, Count:=1)
            r = s.Range
            If s.ShapeRange.Count > 0 Then
                r1.ShapeRange.Select
            Exit Do
            End If
    Loop
```

Comment: Please read the guidance on how to ask a question on stack overflow and then update your code to at least provide the declarations of f,r,s,r1.  In the meantime you are setting the search criteria on a range specified by the current selection but doing the search on a different range specified by f.

Comment: Sorry my bad, Please find the correct code below

Dim r as Object
With Selection.Find
.Text = Text
.Replacement.Text = ""
.Forward = True
.Wrap = 1
.Format = False
.MatchCase = match_case
.MatchWholeWord = match_whole_word
.MatchWildcards = False
.MatchSoundsLike = False
.MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
    Do While .Execute = True
            Selection.Next(Unit:=wdParagraph, Count:=1)
            r = Selection.Range
            If Selection.ShapeRange.Count > 0 Then
                r.ShapeRange.Select
            Exit Do
            End If
    Loop